# problem in generating a reference

Tags: cross-referencing

I had a problem with this reference, can someone assist me with it?. I do not know what could be wrong!.

```
@article{nnnnn, 
author = {hku khfd}, 
journal = {Opt. Express}, 
keywords = {Guided waves; Surface plasmons},
number = {10}, 
pages = {329-335}, 
publisher = {OSA},
title = {Plasmon-polariton modes guided by a metal film of finite width bounded by different dielectrics}, 
volume = {7}, 
month = {Nov},
year = {2000},
url = {http://www.opticsexpress.org/abstract.cfm/URI=oe-7-10-329},
doi = {10.1364/OE.7.000329},
abstract = {hjjkjkgffdfs.},
}

@article{Jestl:89, 
  author   = {M. Jestl and I. Maran and A. K\"{o}ck and W. Beinstingl and E. Gornik}, 
  journal  = {Opt. Lett.}, 
  keywords = {}, 
  number   = {14}, 
  pages    = {719--721}, 
  publisher= {OSA}, 
  title    = {Polarization-sensitive surface plasmon Schottky detectors}, 
  volume   = {14}, 
  month    = {Jul}, 
  year     = {1989}, 
  url      = {ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-14-14-719}, 
  doi      = {10.1364/OL.14.000719}, 
  abstract = {A polarization detectory.}, 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem, more precisely?

Comment: At first look, you have an extra comma after the last entry, this could probably cause "problems", but without more details it may not be the only thing to fix.

Comment: T.Verron, the reference does not show in the pdf after compiling. I ran bibtex twice and I still see a question mark where I should see the reference number!.Also, the comma you mentioned works fine with another reference. Below is the reference that works fine:

Comment: You should edit your question to include this description of the problem, and a compilable minimal working example (MWE) showing the problem (it will probably at least contain the `\cite` command, and the relevant code to make the document compilable). You can (and should) format long code blocks by clicking `{}` in the editor button, in questions and answers. (Long code samples shouldn't appear in comments)

Comment: try to remove the url, to check if the problem is related to this field

Comment: yeah!. it was the url and some unacceptable sambles in the abstract which I did not include. I copeied the url from its page and pasted it, it finally worked!.

Comment: Glad it worked, I turned the comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated which bibliography style you use. Since your bib entries feature the fields `doi` and `url`, be sure to use a bibliography style that recognizes these fields and knows what to do with them. For instance, you could use `plainnat.bst` along with the `natbib` package. Be sure to load either the `url` or the `hyperref` package so that LaTeX can handle URL-type character strings.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{nnnnn, 
author = {Pierre Berini}, 
journal = {Opt. Express}, 
keywords = {Guided waves; Surface plasmons},
number = {10}, 
pages = {329-335}, 
publisher = {OSA},
title = {Plasmon-polariton modes guided by a metal film of finite width bounded by different dielectrics}, 
volume = {7}, 
month = {Nov},
year = {2000},
url = {http://www.opticsexpress.org/abstract.cfm/URI=oe-7-10-329},
doi = {10.1364/OE.7.000329},
}
@article{Jestl:89, 
  author   = {M. Jestl and I. Maran and A. K{\"o}ck and W. Beinstingl and E. Gornik}, 
  journal  = {Opt. Lett.}, 
  keywords = {}, 
  number   = {14}, 
  pages    = {719--721}, 
  publisher= {OSA}, 
  title    = {Polarization-sensitive surface plasmon {Schottky} detectors}, 
  volume   = {14}, 
  month    = {July}, 
  year     = {1989}, 
  url      = {ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-14-14-719}, 
  doi      = {10.1364/OL.14.000719}, 
} 
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib,url}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}  
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If a missing bibliography style would be the reason, why did the second article `Jestl:89` work? It also contains an url

Comment: @samcarter - For now, we don't know which bibliography style (if any!) the OP uses, do we?

Comment: You are right, we do not know, which style the OP used. But from the fact, that the second article works fine, we might conclude, that the OP uses a style which can handle urls and dois.

Answer (score 1):

The `URL`-field is known to cause problems when wired characters sneak into it

Try to reenter the URL

> http://www.opticsinfobase.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-7-10-329

or (in my opinion better)

> http://dx.doi.org/10.1364/OE.7.000329